# fullcalendar eventOrder with several feed sources

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I know that events can be ordered via eventOrder, but I can't get the setting to work with several feed sources via eventSources in month view and week vew with +(*)more.

It works if events all fit inside the day window either in month or week view.

Day view works.

I tried several eventOrder alone or combided 'start,id,color'.

I basically just want the first feed occupancy.php (1 event) to always show on top in any view with or without +(*)More

```
eventSources: [
{
url: 'occupancy.php',
allDayDefault: true,
},
{
url: 'feed.php',
allDayDefault: false,
}
]

eventOrder: 'allDay',
```

Comment: The events will be shown in the order defined by eventOrder. Nothing more, nothing less. The source they came from is irrelevant, only the times (and the eventOrder setting) matters. AFAIK there's nothing you can do about that.

Comment: Is it the event duration taking precedence over allDay events? Can the fullcalendar.js be changed so allDay events rank first over any other order.

Comment: Heres what I'm getting https://postimg.cc/image/9wp5sx2zh/ day 3 to 8 the allDay event is not showing on top.

Comment: Which one is the all day event and why do you expect it to be on top? Don't forget I can't see your data, and I don't know precisely what you were expecting (or hoping) would happen.

Comment: Thanks for replying. 1 feed is allDay and just takes care of the occupancy,  screenshot (the square with percentage). I would this feed to be always on top of everything else from the other feed... including the other feed long duration events.

Comment: As per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventOrder, "events with longer durations and earlier start times are sorted above other events". This is a built-in behaviour. Therefore your longer events will always be placed above the single-day ones. Like I said in the first comment, there's nothing you can do about it, short of modifying the fullCalendar source code yourself. Or you could make a feature request if no-one has already - see https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features, but of course you may not want to wait.

Comment: eventorder should be fully customizable using any built-in parameter or custom parameter passed in events, only after that or if empty would the normal event order apply. The thinking being seems silly to me. I would also need to buy the scheduler plugin, at this point fullcalendar.js does not seem professional enough for the required investment. I will be dropping fullcalendar for another solution. Thanks.

Comment: Scheduler.js won't solve this particular problem. I agree it's not ideal, but as far as I can see fullcalendar is a work in progress, done by someone part time with a handful of other contributors. It's open source, so if you want it to be better then you could always decide to contribute code or cash. Personally it's always met my needs so I never have needed to, but if that changed I would consider putting some code in. It's also IMO the best of the available free/cheap calendar plugins you can get, but I wish you good luck in sourcing an adequate replacement.